# Big Query is not able to convert String to Timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table where one of the column (publishTs) is timeStamp. I am trying to upload a parquet file into same table using GCP UI BQ upload option having same column name (publishTs) with String datatype (e.g.  “2021-08-24T16:06:21.122Z “), But BQ is complaining with following error :-

[image]

I am generating parquet file using Apache Spark. I tried searching on internet but could not get the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to generate this column as INT64 - [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#type_conversions)
[image]

Comment: :- Generating as int64 means generating an epoch time in miliseconds ? As i am using Spark to pull the data and generate the parquet file, what would be datatype for int64 in java , would it be long ?

Comment: i converted timestamp string to Long datatype and tries to upload to BigQuery which worked.